# RNetLogo error building parameter list with NLReport

Tags: r

I use an R script for parameter sweeping in a NetLogo model. The script opens the model correctly with NLStart and NLLoadModel. In the sweeping loop, I store the values of input parameters by building a list:

```
    run.params <- list(
    RD = NLReport("RD?"),
    RD.unif = NLReport("RD-unif?"),
    Gini = NLReport("gini"),
    Gamma = NLReport("gamma"),
    GROUP = NLReport("GROUP?"),
    SN = NLReport("SN?"),
    Group.size = NLReport("group-size"),
    Sn.size = NLReport("sn-size"),
    W.group = NLReport("w-group"),
    W.sn = NLReport("w-sn"),
    Num.sn <- NLReport("num-sn"),
    LF <- NLReport("LF?"),
    L.memory <- NLReport("L-memory"),
    LF.agents <- NLReport("LF-agents?"),
    MASS.enthusiasm <- NLReport("MASS-enthusiasm?"),
    W.crowd <- NLReport("w-crowd")
    )
```

The results are as follows:

```
   $RD
   [1] FALSE
   ...
   $Sn.size
   [1] 5

   $W.group
   [1] 0.05

   $W.sn
   [1] 0.05

   [[11]]
   [1] 2

   [[12]]
   [1] FALSE

   [[13]]
   [1] 5

   [[14]]
   [1] FALSE

   [[15]]
   [1] FALSE

   [[16]]
   [1] 0.01
```

i.e after W.group, the values are retrieved correctly (as checked by launching NetLogo outside R) but the names are missing. I don't know why this is happening. I would be grateful for any help on that.

Comment: After W.sn, switch to using `<-` which is bad in this case. Always use `=` to assign names to list elements.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem. I'm sorry for being so sloppy...